# VBA, calling variable from another sub to class module public property

Tags: vba

How can I change my variables `pjiraUSER` and `pjiraPW` to get my variables from my other sub. I would like to use "Username" and "Password" from my login_credentials sub.

[image]

**Other sub:**

```
Sub login_credentials()
'PURPOSE: Log into Company's Database via Excel VBA & Desktop Text File

Dim Username As String
Dim Password As String
Dim TextFile As Integer
Dim FilePath As String
Dim Credentials As Variant

FilePath = "C:\Users\Desktop\Credentials.txt"
    
    TextFile = FreeFile
    
    'Open the text file
      Open FilePath For Input As TextFile
    
    'Store file content inside array variable and determine login info
      Credentials = Split(Input(LOF(TextFile), TextFile), ",")
        Username = Credentials(0)
        Password = Credentials(1)
    
    'Close Text File
      Close TextFile
  

  
End Sub
```

Comment: you cant make `pjiraUSER` and `pjiraPW` get it from other places. (Edit: You can, is just more complex.) But you can update it just fine by setting them again. Instead of `Username = Credentials(0)` try `pjiraUSER = Credentials(0)` and it should now have that value.

Comment: Ah I see. But what would i set pjiraUSER and pjiraPW to in my image section?

Comment: It doesnt matter, `Sub login_crdentials()` is just going to override whatever you set them to.

Comment: but dont i need to get `Sub login_crdentials()` called? I cant just have it in a module without it being triggered by anything right?

Comment: `pjiraUSER = Value` and `pjiraPW = Value` inside your image section?

Comment: @BrianMStafford , yes I have tried that. getting errors, maybe something else is wrong here. I dont actively called the `Sub login_credentials` sub

Comment: You have to call something, that includes that code or that calls login_credentials, or you can set it on the Open/Initialization of the File/Form. But you have to tie it to an event if you want it automatically updated.